# running a batch file when the first one complete

Tags: batch-file, wait

i have 3 batch files

-First.bat (to execute an .exe program that take a while to generate a report) :

```
start /WAIT /W /B "" "C:\program.exe"
```

-Second.bat (to rename the generated file and move it to an other location )

-Third.bat (to call the First.bat Then the  Second.bat) here is how i write it :

```
echo batch controller
call "C:\First.bat"
echo booo
call "C:\Second.bat"
echo batch controller running again
```

the problem is that the second.bat is executed before the first.bat terminate although i write

```
start /WAIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

```
echo batch controller & call "C:\First.bat" & echo booo & call "C:\Second.bat" & echo batch controller running again
```

Command after `&` will be executed only after the one before it has finished.

Comment: look what kind of message was shown to me : 
Batch controller boo the system cannot find the file specified A duplicate file name exists, or the the file cannot be found (the report was not generated yet)
batch controller running again
 then , the generating process start

Comment: This error seems unrelated to the command using `&`.  Try executing individual commands to figure the problem.

Comment: individually it works Fine , the problem is that the Second.bat start executing before the First.bat terminate , (the Second.bat used to rename and move the generated report this why the error message is shown( the system cannot find the file specified A "duplicate file name exists, or the the file cannot be found")

Comment: simply say `call "C:\program.exe"` in the first batch file.

Comment: it's working , thank you ,
but I Have a remark : 
with start /wait /B "" "C:\program.exe" it  doesn't work i don't know why !!

Comment: See if [procman](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can help you figure what's happening

Comment: your solution for using "&" is amazing but I have a last question : 
when the First.bat terminate i have to click Enter to start the second.bat , how can I proceed to make it start automatically just when the First bat terminate ?

Comment: when the First.bat terminate i have to click Enter to start the second.bat , how can I proceed to make it start automatically just when the First bat terminate  ?